# MVC Many to many search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, many-to-many

i have three tables in my model class

```
public class Objekat
{

    [Key]
    public int ObjekatID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Naziv Objekta")]
    public String Naziv { get; set; }
    public int?  KategorijaID { get; set; }
    public int[] idZanrova { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Zanr> Zanr { get; set; }
    public virtual Kategorija Kategorija { get; set; }



}

public class Zanr
{
    public int ZanrID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Naziv Zanra")]
    public string Naziv { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Objekat> Objekat { get; set; }

}

public class Kategorija
{
    public int KategorijaID { get; set; }
    public string  Naziv { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Objekat> Objekat { get; set; }
}

public class KatalogContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Objekat> Objekti { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Zanr> Zanrovi { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Kategorija> Kategorije { get; set; }

    public KatalogContext() : base("MojaBaza") { }

}
```

Is it possible to make a filter for showing only data from table "Objekat" witch contains specific "Zanrs"?

I suppose the relation between tables "Objekat" and "Zanr" are ok ?

Comment: Can you clean up that code, get rid of unwanted properties, and make your question more clear?

Comment: Does this make sense?